# Rails passing data from a view to a different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, view

I am trying to pass a int value from one view to a controller. The view and controller are not related. So in one view I display a int value, I want to click on that int value and be redirected to another view which will display some content based on my int value from the previous view. Can anyone help me with the code please.

At this point the controller which will receive the int value, it receives that value only if I added manually.

Thank you

Comment: You can manually add GET params to a link: `/users/index?extra_param=12` will lead you to the Index action of User Controller with a param like this: `params[:extra_param]` which would be equal to 12 in this example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create a custom action in that controller.

```
class YourController

    def custom_action_for_different_view
      @your_integer = params[:id]
      render or redirect_to
    end

end
```

You would also need to add an entry in your routes.rb so rails nows how to handle the route.

```
get "custom_url" => "your_controller#custom_action_for_different_view"
```

and of course use that url in your first view (which displays the integer which will be clicked).